# Can't build maven Vaadin 11 starter pack, missing dependency?

Tags: maven, vaadin

I can't build the maven Vaadin 11 starter pack like mentioned in the tutorial section of the doc. It seems that a package is missing, which provide an @Helper annotation. I tried to add the dependency in the pom.xml but no luck.

Here's the log from Maven :

```html
-------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.653 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-15T11:30:01+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project my-starter-project: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/olivierbatard/Java/Vaadin/my-starter-project/src/main/java/org/hammicus/vaadin/Customer.java:[5,44] package com.vaadin.flow.tutorial.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/olivierbatard/Java/Vaadin/my-starter-project/src/main/java/org/hammicus/vaadin/Customer.java:[12,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class Helper
[ERROR] /Users/olivierbatard/Java/Vaadin/my-starter-project/src/main/java/org/hammicus/vaadin/CustomerStatus.java:[3,44] package com.vaadin.flow.tutorial.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/olivierbatard/Java/Vaadin/my-starter-project/src/main/java/org/hammicus/vaadin/CustomerStatus.java:[5,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class Helper
[ERROR] /Users/olivierbatard/Java/Vaadin/my-starter-project/src/main/java/org/hammicus/vaadin/CustomerService.java:[12,44] package com.vaadin.flow.tutorial.annotations does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/olivierbatard/Java/Vaadin/my-starter-project/src/main/java/org/hammicus/vaadin/CustomerService.java:[21,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class Helper
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

When I add the dependency in the pom :

```html
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.982 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-15T11:38:43+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-starter-project: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.hammicus.vaadin:my-starter-project:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.vaadin:flow-documentation-parent:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT in Vaadin Directory (http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Here is the pom.xml section with the dependency I added :

```html
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
      <artifactId>flow-documentation-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Here is the link to the tutorial : https://vaadin.com/docs/v11/flow/introduction/tutorial-get-started.html

Does anyone know how to fix the dependency ?

Comment: Could you add a link to the tutorial you're referring to?

Comment: I added the link to the question, thanks.

Comment: Really using a SNAPSHOT ?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes that's what is mentioned in the source of flow-documentation-parent pom https://github.com/vaadin/flow-and-components-documentation/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: If Vaadin provides a new release of their framework I expect that all artifacts are available as releases via Central and not as SNAPSHOT's cause you can't rely on a SNAPSHOT version...

Comment: if you use snapshot-versions you need to provide the repository where the snapshots can be found. ```<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories> ```

Comment: True. But this artifact at this version seems not to be available vi central hence my problem.

Comment: @Dirk -> I tried that, no luck same error at build. but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all references to the `@Helper` annotation from the code. It's only used by our own internal tests that verify the tutorial code compiles.

I've created [a ticket](https://github.com/vaadin/flow-and-components-documentation/issues/267) about fixing the tutorial and/or the code so that this shouldn't be an issue in the future.